# insert only if fb_id does not already exist - else do nothing - PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I'm sure there are very similar questions to this one on here but upon doing countless searches like this, all I have been coming up with is ones for other languages other than PHP or slightly different constructs that throw off what I am trying to do and causes errors.  SO please excuse me if it sounds a little redundant.

I have the following code that enters data into the MySQL databse just fine and works...

---

```
mysql_connect("" . $db_server_name . "", "" . $db_username . "", "" . $db_password . "") or die(mysql_error()); mysql_select_db("" . $db_database_name . "") or die(mysql_error()); 

mysql_query("INSERT INTO users (fb_id,fb_name,fb_first_name,fb_last_name,fb_profile_link,fb_username,fb_birthday,fb_gender,fb_email,fb_locale,reg_date,app_points,app_submissions,app_sub_available,app_wins) VALUES ( 'item','item','item','item','item','item','item','item','item','item','item','item','item','item','item' )"); 

echo "Your table has been populated";
```

---

But I simply want the following...

1. To check and see if the fb_id already exists (which is known locally as `$user_id` variable) ...in other words it will see if `$user_id` already exists in the tabe where fb_id is.
2. Insert the data (from the working code above) if it does not exist.
3. Print "It already exists" if it does exist.

I know this seems like a simple fix for many of you but oddly enough, I have never had to do this before so it's not so simple for me.

Thanks A Bunch for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE fb_id = $fb_id") or die(mysql_error());
if(!mysql_num_rows($data)){
mysql_query("INSERT INTO users (fb_id,fb_name,fb_first_name,fb_last_name,fb_profile_link,fb_username,fb_birthday,fb_gender,fb_email,fb_locale,reg_date,app_points,app_submissions,app_sub_available,app_wins) VALUES ( 'item','item','item','item','item','item','item','item','item','item','item','item','item','item','item' )"); 

    echo "Your table has been populated";
}esle{
    echo "Id Already exist!";
}
```

Comment: Well for a minute there, I was really cofused as to why this wasn't working.  Just notice the word "else" being mispelled.  Fixed that and it worked perfectly.  Exactly what I was looking for.  Thank you!

Comment: ...oh and I changed the "fb_id = $fb_id" to "fb_id = $user_id".

Answer (score 0):

so why not do a "select fb_id as user_id from users where fb_id=$user_id" then if that returns no rows do the insert.